# Filtering Using GREP

Tags: regex, awk, grep, cut

The Question is like
**Find those names who have got number greater than equal to m but less than n.**
A ".csv" file is given. It is preferable to solve this using grep (regex) .

---

I am going like this:

```
cat abc.csv|cut -f 3,7 -d ","|grep "4[4-9][0-9]*"|head
```

But it is giving me other than desired

***NOTE*** column 3 is person's name and column 7 is the corresponding number of those people.

Any suggestion to solve this will be very helpful.

---

Comment: 1) you need `4[0-9][0-9]` to match `400` to `499` 2) use `,4[0-9][0-9]` (note the comma) so that the match isn't performed anywhere in the column

Comment: Thanks Sundeep. It works. Can u please say what is role of that comma and If I want to display only unique value of column 3 what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your tried efforts. Please do add your samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hello Ravinder, I have updated. Can U please check?

Comment: @NobitaNobi, Could you please update samples of input and expected output in form of text in your question, images/links are not encouraged. Thank you.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sh
cut -d, -f 3,7 Bulk.csv | grep ',4[0-9][0-9][^0-9]' | cut -d, -f 1
```

Explanation: `cat` is not necessary. The expression `[^0-9]` means everything except a digit; using only `,4[0-9][0-9]` as regex would select also lines containing numbers with more digits before the decimal point, like `4247.14`, which is not what you want.

We miss a sample of your input file `Bulk.csv` to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know,
I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.
```

*(see https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ for reference).*

This isn't a good example of how to use `grep` as it's well documented that using a regexp to do a numeric comparison is a far more difficult and fragile approach than just comparing numbers, e.g. with `awk`, and that using `grep` on a line when your data is in a specific field is also more difficult and fragile than using a tool that understands fields, e.g. `awk` again.

The right way to test for the contents of a field being in a numeric range is to do a numeric comparison on just that field:

```
awk -F, '(440<=$7) && ($7<500){print $3}' abc.csv
```

I'm guessing at the values you want the range to have based on the regexp you tried in your question, if I guessed wrong just change them.

I see from some other answers that you do not want to print lines where `$7` contains a `.` or maybe it's that you only want lines where `$7` is an integer. If so then that's a trivial and appropriate thing to use a regexp to test for:

```
awk -F, '($7 !~ /\./) && (440<=$7) && ($7<500){print $3}' abc.csv
```

or:

```
awk -F, '($7 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) && (440<=$7) && ($7<500){print $3}' abc.csv
```

Hopefully you can see how clear, simple, robust and easy to modify in future that is vs trying to do the same with a regexp across a line using grep.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pattern printing the values from column 3 where column 7 is in the range of 400-499 with only `awk` instead of piping through multiple programs.

The pattern `^4[0-9][0-9]$` uses anchors `^` and `$` to prevent partial matches and 2 ranges 0-9 to match 400 to 499.

```
awk -F, '
$7 ~ /^4[0-9][0-9]$/ {
  print $3
}
' abc.csv
```

---

If you can use `gnu grep`, you can match the value of the 3rd field, if the 7th field in in range 400-499, but it is a long pattern and I would recommend using awk.

```
^(?:[^,]*,){2}\K[^,\n]+(?=(?:,[^,\n]*){3},\s*4[0-9][0-9](?=\s*,|$))
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^,]*,){2}` Match the first 2 comma separated fields
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^,]+` Match the 3rd field
- `(?=` Positive lookahead assertion

  - `(?:,[^,\n]*){3},\s*4[0-9][0-9](?=\s*,|$)` Match the 7th field to be a value 400-499 between followed by either a comma or the end of the string to prevent a partial match
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1KU8d/1)

For example

```
grep -oP "^(?:[^,]*,){2}\K[^,]+(?=(?:,[^,]*){3},\s*4[0-9][0-9](?=\s*,|$))" abc.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the name then you have to add:

`cut -f 1 -d ","`

If you need only real numers between 400.00 and 499.99 (as I see from your result) then grep should be:

`grep "4[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]"`

If you need to admit any number of decimals and also integers and take care of optional trailing spaces and end of line($) you can use:

`grep -E "4[0-9][0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]*)* *$"`

If you need to be sure it does not match 1400 or names that contains 400 then you should use:

`grep -E " *, *4[0-9][0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]*)* *$"`

We can go on, but I will stop here.
My proposal is to use this:

`cat Bulk.csv | cut -f 3,7 -d "," | grep -E " *, *4[0-9][0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]*)* *$" | cut -f 1 -d ","`

Comment: Thanks but 4214.00 like numbers will also pass through this regular expression. Which I do not want

Comment: You are right we have to add end of line.

Comment: If you want to avoid awk and have integers instead of real then you can pass name and number as argumets to a shell script and use shell test function in order to obtain the result. Test will be something like: [ $7 -gt 400 ] && [ $7 -lt 500 ] && echo $3